# How to build a customized dataset from MNIST in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, dataset, mnist, torchvision

I am importing MNIST dataset as `train_data_MNIST = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root=path+"MNIST", train=True,transform=transforms, download=True)`and I am trying to make a smaller dataset from MNIST, let's say the first 10,000 images and corresponding labels. I know this can be handled with `torch.utils.data.Subset`. But what I want is a `torchvision.datasets` object (if I directly apply `torch.utils.data.Subset` to the `train_data_MNIST` that I list above, the result is an object from `torch.utils.data.Subset` class).
Is there any possible way such that I can use a fraction of the original MNIST dataset to create a new **dataset** (not **subset**)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use a `torch.utils.data.Subset`? It was designed for your case in particular. Plus it inherit from vanilla Dataset so it supports the same API.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. In my question description, I have explained that I have tried `torch.utils.data.Subset` and that is not what I needed.

Comment: Ok but what's wrong with `Subset` concretely? (note that an instance of `Subset` is also an instance of `Dataset`)

Answer (score 0):

What about modifying `data` and `targets` directly? For example:

```
dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root=path+"MNIST", train=True,transform=transforms, download=True)
dataset.data = dataset.data[:10000]
dataset.targets = dataset.targets[:10000]
```